# 2015 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

The 2015 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://music.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).  If you have questions for moderator candidates, please add them as answers to [this post](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2304/28).

Comment: Is there any idea how many moderators you hope to elect?

Comment: @Mr.Boy it's 3 and you can always find this information on the election page.

Comment: @dom thanks - I spotted the right-hand side-bar with loads of information now. I am so used to that being full of adds/questions I blanked it out!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the election is over!  [Results](http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/q/2325/28)